# Data binding in C# (WP8.1) while setting datacontext of stackpanel not working

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, data-binding

Code that does not work:

```
<ListView x:Name="list_lapTimes" 
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
          Grid.Row="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding RecTimes}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            DataContext="SplitTime">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Hours, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}" 
                               FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="30">:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Minutes, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}" 
                               FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="30">:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Seconds, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}" 
                               FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">.</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Milliseconds, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}, ConverterParameter=something}" 
                               FontSize="15"
                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code that does work:

```
<ListView x:Name="list_lapTimes" 
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
          Grid.Row="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding RecTimes}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SplitTime.Hours, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}" 
                               FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="30">:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SplitTime.Minutes, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}" 
                               FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="30">:</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SplitTime.Seconds, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}}" 
                               FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">.</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SplitTime.Milliseconds, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverter}, ConverterParameter=something}" 
                               FontSize="15"
                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Below is a part of my Page class -->

```
public ObservableCollection<TimeSnap> RecTimes { get; set; }

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    sw = new Stopwatch(Dispatcher);
    RecTimes = new ObservableCollection<TimeSnap>();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

And here is the TimeSnap class -->

```
public class TimeSnap
{
    public TimeSpan LapTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan SplitTime { get; set; }
}
```

The difference between the two xaml codes is that in the first one I set the `DataContext` of the `StackPanel` inside the `DataTemplate` to `SplitTime` and then use simply the name of the properties in the `TextBlocks` inside the stackpanel (e.g. `Hours`).

In the second xaml code I do not set any `DataContext` of the `StackPanel` and in the textboxes I use the full path in the binding for textblocks (e.g. `SplitTime.Hours`).

The second approach works but, I need it to work the first way. From what I know the both approaches should mean the same binding path. But in the first approach I get the following binding error:

> Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Hours' property not found on '`` Windows.Foundation.IReference`1<String> ``'. BindingExpression: Path='Hours' DataItem='Windows.Foundation.IReference`1'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
>
> Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Minutes' property not found on '`` Windows.Foundation.IReference`1<String> ``'. BindingExpression: Path='Minutes' DataItem='Windows.Foundation.IReference`1'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
>
> Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Seconds' property not found on '`` Windows.Foundation.IReference`1<String> ``'. BindingExpression: Path='Seconds' DataItem='Windows.Foundation.IReference`1'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
>
> Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Milliseconds' property not found on '`` Windows.Foundation.IReference`1<String> ``'. BindingExpression: Path='Milliseconds' DataItem='Windows.Foundation.IReference`1'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same syntax when you bind to a `DataContext`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
      Grid.Column="0" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      DataContext="{Binding SplitTime}">
```

The rest of your code looks fine to me.

**UPDATE**
If you are binding the model to the `Page.DataContext`, I suggest to go with:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
      Grid.Column="0" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      DataContext="{Binding DataContext.SplitTime, ElementName=list_lapTimes}">
```

**UPDATE 2**
StackPanel does not need any DataContext binding because it automatically inherits the data from the ListView. 
For each TextBox  you should use:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SplitTime, Converter={StaticResource TimeSecondConverter}}" 
                               FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
```

'
And use a different Converter to display seconds, minutes etc.

Comment: Actually I did write it like you said -- DataContext="{Binding SplitTime}". I by mistake wrote it here like that. So, that's not really the problem. Could you see if there's anything else that's wrong in this?

Comment: I use a different approach. On the code behind, how do you set the datacontext?

Comment: well in the code behind I have set the Page's DataContext = this. All the other bindings in the page works including my second code I mentioned in the question. The problem comes when I try to set the StackPanel's datacontext. Btw, is there a better approach to this?

Comment: I need some help here. My ListView ItemSource is binded to RecTimes. RecTimes is an ObserableCollection<TimeSnap> object. The TimeSnap class contains two properties SplitTime and LapTime and both are of type TimeSpan. So what should I really write in the DataContext. I am confused.

Comment: You should post a scratch of your ModelView

Comment: I have added the TimeSnap class code and a part of my page class. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by creating a wrapper class for TimeSpan. I believe that TimeSpan being a struct was the problem. I am not sure however.
Anyway I added the following class -->

```
public class TimeSpanCustom
{
    TimeSpan ts;
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public int Minutes { get; set; }
    public int Seconds { get; set; }
    public int Milliseconds { get; set; }

    public TimeSpanCustom(int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds, int milliseconds)
    {
        this.Hours = hours;
        this.Minutes = minutes;
        this.Seconds = seconds;
        this.Milliseconds = milliseconds;
        ts = new TimeSpan(days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
    }

    public TimeSpanCustom Subtract(TimeSpanCustom ts)
    {
        TimeSpan minuend = new TimeSpan(0, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds);
        TimeSpan result = this.ts.Subtract(minuend);
        return new TimeSpanCustom(0, result.Hours, result.Minutes, result.Seconds, result.Milliseconds);
    }
}
```

And changed the TimeSnap class to use TimeSpanCustom instead of TimeSpan.

```
public class TimeSnap
{
    public TimeSpanCustom LapTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpanCustom SplitTime { get; set; }
}
```

Now the 1st xaml code works.